# overflow div собственный скроллинг

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, прокрутка

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать собственный скроллинг в элементе, задав у блока `overflow`. Мне необходимо заменить стандартные полосы прокрутки, появляющиеся в случае, если контент больше размеров блока, на свой пользовательский скролл. Могу предположить, что надо выставлять у блока `overflow: hidden`, добавить две стрелки и юзать `js/jquery`. Если можно, то наведите на пример кода `DOM`.

Comment: ну есть же большое количество готовых примеров, почему Вы пишите сюда? Тут люди отвечаю на проблемные вопросы связанные с кодом, или подсказывают как реализовать что либо,  а не пишут его просто так

Comment: Используйте Google - [стилизация полосы прокрутки](https://www.google.ru/?ion=1&espv=2#newwindow=1&q=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: насколько я помню, мне довольно удобным показался плагин nanoScrollerJS http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Answer (score 1):

Небольшой перечень почти готовых решений вашего вопроса через jquery ui
https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/scrollbar/

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.